# Solid Geometry Question

Tags: geometry

The base ABCD of the pyramid ABCDP is a rectangle with sides 6
and 8. The edge P A = 6 is the altitude of the pyramid. Find the distance between
P A and BD. Find the surface area of the pyramid.

Not sure if distance of PA to BD is 5?
Also, need some help with surface area.  It is the area of the rectangle plus the area of the faces.  Area the areas of the faces: (6)(8)/2, (6)(8)/2, (6)$(\sqrt{91}$)/2,
(6)(6)/2.  For a surface area of  114+3$\sqrt{91}$.

Comment: The perpendicular distance betwen $PA$ and $BD$ is the length of the segment $AH$ where $AH$ is the altitude in triangle $ABD$

Comment: Distance of $PA$ to $BD$ is $4.8$. Two of your face areas are wrong: notice that $PB$ is the altitude of face $PBC$, and $PD$ is the altitude of face $PDC$.